# why is my Dart function slower than the latter one on this codewar challenge?

Tags: flutter, performance, dart

the challenge states
'*You are given an array (which will have a length of at least 3, but could be very large) containing integers. The array is either entirely comprised of odd integers or entirely comprised of even integers except for a single integer N. Write a method that takes the array as an argument and returns this "outlier" N.

Examples
[2, 4, 0, 100, 4, 11, 2602, 36] -->  11 (the only odd number)

[160, 3, 1719, 19, 11, 13, -21] --> 160 (the only even number)*'

My first solution was this:

```
     int find(List integers) {
     
      var m = new Map();
      m[1] = [];
      m[0] = [];
      int i = 0;
      while(m[1].isEmpty || m[0].isEmpty || i <= 2){
        m[integers[i].abs()%2].add(integers[i]);
        i++;    
      }
      
    return m[1].length>1? m[0][0] : m[1][0];  
    }
```

It took about 5 seconds... Later this other solution showed on my screen:

```
int find(List integers) {

  List<int> even = [];
  List<int> odds = [];
  integers.forEach((number) => (number.isEven) ? even.add(number) : odds.add(number) );
  return (even.length == 1) ? even[0] : odds[0];

}
```

I tested it on my PC and it ran for 3 seconds... isn't this latter solution looping twice over the list? I thought mine would be faster because it wouldn't always need to get to the last element. What happened here?

Comment: Why do you think the second solution would loop over the list twice?

Comment: O nevermind, I realized it only does one.... but still I thought mine would not always do it since if the list's length is 10 and the outlier is 4 it would return....

Comment: It might be faster in very specific situations, but on average your solution is probably slower for large lists because of the conditions you are checking every iteration and maybe because of suboptimal memory access. But this is just me guessing.

Comment: Also, not sure why you are using Map or List, and not Set.  I would think you can accumulate into a Map<bool, Set<int>> rather quickly.